# How solve Failed to set the 'value' property type filename JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code:

```
data-whateverpathfoto="<?php echo $row['pathfoto']; ?>" //get path image database.
```

Catch get and attribute in js:

```
var recipientpathfoto = button.data('whateverpathfoto')
modal.find('#pathfoto').val(recipientcaminhofoto)
```

In console.log, returno error:

> ncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

How can I solve it?

Comment: The error is because `#pathfoto` is an `input type="file"` element whose value cannot be set programmatically for security reasons. All you can do is empty the field.

Comment: but since I'm setting those attributes to do an update in the database, I'll need it to bring the file path.
Do you have any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could store the file path in a [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).